# How i write simple mysql query in codeigniter model

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, model-view-controller, model

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
  SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(process_disposition.sub_dispo, ',', numbers.n), ',', -1) name
FROM
  (SELECT 1 n UNION ALL SELECT 2
   UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4) numbers INNER JOIN process_disposition
    ON CHAR_LENGTH(process_disposition.sub_dispo)
     -CHAR_LENGTH(REPLACE(process_disposition.sub_dispo, ',', ''))>=numbers.n-1
```

Comment: I want to write this in a model of Codeigniter 3 framework

Answer (score 0):

You can write it like this

```
$query = $this->db->query("
                       SELECT DISTINCT SUBSTRING_INDEX
(SUBSTRING_INDEX(process_disposition.sub_dispo, ',', numbers.n), ',', -1)name FROM 
(SELECT 1 n UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4)numbers
INNER JOIN process_disposition ON CHAR_LENGTH(process_disposition.sub_dispo)
-CHAR_LENGTH(REPLACE(process_disposition.sub_dispo, ',', ''))>=numbers.n-1"
);

if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
return $query->result();
} else {
return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do it.

```
$this->db->select("DISTINCT SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(process_disposition.sub_dispo, ',', numbers.n), ',', -1) name");
$this->db->from("(SELECT 1 n UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4) numbers")
$this->db->join("process_disposition", "CHAR_LENGTH(process_disposition.sub_dispo)-CHAR_LENGTH(REPLACE(process_disposition.sub_dispo, ',', ''))>=numbers.n-1", "INNER");
$result = $this->db->get();
```

Comment: when I am using this unwanted space is it automatically in query 
see echo $this->db->last_query(); this gave me

Comment: SELECT DISTINCT SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(process_disposition.sub_dispo, ', ', numbers.n), ', ', -1) sub_dispo FROM (SELECT 1 n UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4) numbers INNER JOIN `process_disposition` ON CHAR_LENGTH(process_disposition.sub_dispo)-CHAR_LENGTH(REPLACE(process_disposition.sub_dispo, ',', ''))>=numbers.n-1